# C: Bitwise NOT on certain bit

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

My question is rather simple, yet I cannot find an easy solution:
I have an integer greater or eqal 16, so at least `1000` in binary. I wish to flip the third bit using the bitwise NOT operator. In this case, it would be `1100`.

Is there any operator which could do this? The `~`-operator flips all bits as far as I know, not just one certain.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Sorry, this is no homework, just pure curiousity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XOR with the bits that you want to flip.

```
int c = 0x10; // 10000b
int m = 0x08; // 01000b
c ^= m;       // 11000b
```

Comment: @larsmans Thanks! I "dropped" the last zero on all three. It is now fixed.

Comment: Actually, it seems like I should have thought about XOR earlier. Sorry for being so focused about NOT

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
bit_fld ^= (1 << n)
```

where bit_fld is the bit field, and n=3 for third bit.

Answer (score 3):

Now what you call 'flip' is actually called XOR.
XOR in C(++) works like this:

```
int sixteen = 16; // 10000
int twentyfour = sixteen ^ 0x8; // flip the 4th bit. result: 24
int sixteen_again = twentyfour ^ 0x8; // again, flip the 4th bit. result: 16
```

On a side note: 16 in binary is 10000, not 1000.

Answer (score 2):

check this site: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/41493
he has the same problem you have, and a couple of solutions!

```
void flipbit(unsigned* a, unsigned b)
{
    *a ^= (1 << b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    int n = 0;
    int y, i;

    for (i=0 ; i < (int)sizeof(int)*8 ; i++) {
        y = x ^ ~(1<<i);
        printf("x=%x\ti=%d\ty=%x\n", x, i, y);
    }

    x = 0x0;
    for (i=0 ; i < (int)sizeof(int)*8 ; i++) {
        y = x ^ ~(1<<i);
        printf("x=%x\ti=%d\ty=%x\n", x, i, y);
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
Output:
x=ffffffff  i=0 y=1
x=ffffffff  i=1 y=2
x=ffffffff  i=2 y=4
x=ffffffff  i=3 y=8
x=ffffffff  i=4 y=10
x=ffffffff  i=5 y=20
x=ffffffff  i=6 y=40
x=ffffffff  i=7 y=80
x=ffffffff  i=8 y=100
x=ffffffff  i=9 y=200
x=ffffffff  i=10    y=400
x=ffffffff  i=11    y=800
x=ffffffff  i=12    y=1000
x=ffffffff  i=13    y=2000
x=ffffffff  i=14    y=4000
x=ffffffff  i=15    y=8000
x=ffffffff  i=16    y=10000
x=ffffffff  i=17    y=20000
x=ffffffff  i=18    y=40000
x=ffffffff  i=19    y=80000
x=ffffffff  i=20    y=100000
x=ffffffff  i=21    y=200000
x=ffffffff  i=22    y=400000
x=ffffffff  i=23    y=800000
x=ffffffff  i=24    y=1000000
x=ffffffff  i=25    y=2000000
x=ffffffff  i=26    y=4000000
x=ffffffff  i=27    y=8000000
x=ffffffff  i=28    y=10000000
x=ffffffff  i=29    y=20000000
x=ffffffff  i=30    y=40000000
x=ffffffff  i=31    y=80000000
x=0 i=0 y=fffffffe
x=0 i=1 y=fffffffd
x=0 i=2 y=fffffffb
x=0 i=3 y=fffffff7
x=0 i=4 y=ffffffef
x=0 i=5 y=ffffffdf
x=0 i=6 y=ffffffbf
x=0 i=7 y=ffffff7f
x=0 i=8 y=fffffeff
x=0 i=9 y=fffffdff
x=0 i=10    y=fffffbff
x=0 i=11    y=fffff7ff
x=0 i=12    y=ffffefff
x=0 i=13    y=ffffdfff
x=0 i=14    y=ffffbfff
x=0 i=15    y=ffff7fff
x=0 i=16    y=fffeffff
x=0 i=17    y=fffdffff
x=0 i=18    y=fffbffff
x=0 i=19    y=fff7ffff
x=0 i=20    y=ffefffff
x=0 i=21    y=ffdfffff
x=0 i=22    y=ffbfffff
x=0 i=23    y=ff7fffff
x=0 i=24    y=feffffff
x=0 i=25    y=fdffffff
x=0 i=26    y=fbffffff
x=0 i=27    y=f7ffffff
x=0 i=28    y=efffffff
x=0 i=29    y=dfffffff
x=0 i=30    y=bfffffff
x=0 i=31    y=7fffffff
*/
```

I refer [this](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/) link for bit operations in `c`.

Comment: Thanks for keeping an eye on me! I've corrected the mistake! Please continue to correct me whenever I go wrong! :)